# Convert lines of file to dictionary in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Have a file that contains line in a format like below:

```
category1 name=item1
category1 attributes=attr1, attr2
category1 name=item2
category1 attributes=attr1, attr2, attr3
category2 name=item1
category2 attributes=attr1
```

Looking to get a dictionary in ansible like below:

```yaml
- category1:
    - name: item1
      attributes: [attr1, attr2]
    - name: item2
      attributes: [attr1, attr2, attr3]
- category2:
    - name: item1
      attributes: [attr1]
```

I was trying with jinja2 and below is what I get as of now. Problem is that the code is getting complicated after every step. Is there any way using filter or other methods that could produce the expected result with more readable code?

Code:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    converted_data: >-
      {%- set res = dict() -%}
      {%- for line in content.stdout_lines -%}
      {%-   set key_val = line.split(' ', 1) -%}
      {%-   set second_level = [] -%}
      {%-   if res[key_val[0]] is defined -%}
      {%-     set second_level = res[key_val[0]] -%}
      {%-   endif -%}
      {%-   set val_split = key_val[1].split('=') -%}
      {%-   set _ = second_level.append( dict({ val_split[0]: (val_split[1].split(',') | map('trim') | list) }) ) -%}
      {%-   set _ = res.update({key_val[0]: second_level}) -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ res }}
```

Produces:

```
category1:
- name:
  - item1
- attributes:
  - attr1
  - attr2
- name:
  - item2
- attributes:
  - attr1
  - attr2
  - attr3
category2:
- name:
  - item1
- attributes:
  - attr1
```

Comment: Small question: what is the logic behind the fact that in `categroy2`, attributes is an array, although it is the only element and name is a string? You actual output doesn't reflect that either.

Comment: Category `attributes` may contain one or more items. Do not have a particular requirement but having same type makes it easier for processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise you to stop writing this in Jinja and switch to Python. It can be a lookup plugin, a module, or just a very simple script to read from stdin and output a json.

Jinja is not designed for algorithms. Whilst you can implement any efficiently computable function using the turing-complete Jinja2 template language, it's going to be very very painful for you and for anyone else reading your code.

If you do it in Python, you can add few tests (just define few 'test_case1', 'test_case2' functions inside your script and use pytest to run them). Without tests you never will get a stable code for all cases (like if some line is missing, or there is a reordering, or duplicates, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the response. So not much could be done using existing filters or modules?

Comment: You can do anything you want, but it's hard to write and to test. The more logic you have in your jinja, the more brittle it become.